# Bootstrap 3.2: Button group and input group on same line in form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When using Bootstrap 3.2, I'd like to create a form with of 8 column width  (col-sm-8, so full width at small resolution), line by line:

- an input form at 100% width of the 8 columns
- a radio button group, and behind that an input group, where the textbox of the input group takes the full width left over, such that the button group and input group together have the same size as the first line

I fail to create this, as my input group will either move to the next line and/or will not fill the whole width. How to realize this?

```
<div class="container">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label sr-only" for="input_1">Input 1</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_1" placeholder="Input 1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label sr-only" for="input_2">Input 2</label>
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-default active">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked>Opt1</label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2">Opt2</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <span class="input-group-btn" style="width: auto;">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button> 
                        </span>
                        <!-- /btn-group -->
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_2" placeholder="Input 2">
                    </div>
                    <!-- /input-group -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

See also my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00gcsk90/4/) on this.

Many thanks for the replies!

Comment: If I add "display: inline-table; vertical-align: middle;" to the input-group, and "width: auto;" to the input-group-btn, the input group will be on the same line as the button group, but it will not have full width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I've answered my own question in the mean time, by adding

```
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
```

to the form group, and

```
overflow: hidden
```

to the button group.

I also had to delete the

```
width: auto;
```

from the input-group-btn.

For details, see http://jsfiddle.net/00gcsk90/6/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help.

```
<div class="container">
<form role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label sr-only" for="input_1">Input 1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_1" placeholder="Input 1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label sr-only" for="input_2">Input 2</label>
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default active">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked>Opt1</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2">Opt2</label>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-xs-12">Button</button>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_2" placeholder="Input 2">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00gcsk90/5/)

Comment: Not really (but thanks for posting!): at high resolutions there's a large gap between the button-group and the input-group, while al low resolutions the butto-group will take two lines. I'd like the button-group to always be on one line, then a small space (the regular margin) and then the input-group behind that filling the full width.